# Error says that the allowed Cloud ML quota is exceeded, but it is within the limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am using Google AI Online Prediction API and I am currently receiving this kind of error:

> "The allowed Cloud ML quota is exceeded, please see
> https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/ml.googleapis.com/quotas for
> details."

However, when I go to the console, on the mentioned link, I find that the rate of requests per minute is well below the limit:

[image]

Would there be another "hidden" quota which is being exceeded?
When I go the global "quotas page" (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) all the quotas, from all the services, show to be "within limits".

Comment: Exact same problem here. On documentation I found the limit of 6000 requests in 60 seconds too, but doesn't explain the problem though. In my case my peek requests per minute are under 200 requests, and I still receiving some 429 errors just like you.

Comment: Have you tried to report this issue via Google [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) the get this problem visible to product owners?

Comment: @Nick_Kh good idea! I have now reported the issue.